# Enabling gcc-multilib manually after successful gcc installation on Debian system?

Tags: linux, gcc, debian, cross-compiling

I installed gcc-4.7.2 on my i686 Debian system successfully  but i don't know how to enable gcc-multilib after installation.

I installed gcc-4.7.2  on my debian system with configuration "--enable-multilib" but it does not work.

I copied the files(gcc-multilib package files) at the same location mentioned in gcc-multilib package file list though it does not work.

Comment: are you compiling the gcc or using a binary package to install it? If you are using a binary package then probable you have to check `gcc -v` it will give you command line used to compile your copy of gcc. If you are compiling the gcc then give `--enable-multilib` at command line to configure script of gcc.

Comment: I installed gcc-4.7.2 with configure --enable-multilib and --enable-targets=i686-pc-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu And before this configuration for gcc i installed binutils with --enable-targets=i686-pc-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu. And every thing worked fine. I installed gcc-4.7.2 successfuly though also i am not able generate 64bit code using -m64 flag on my 32bit debian machine.

Comment: # gcc -v Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=gcc COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/var/opt/crossgcc/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2‌​/lto-wrapper Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.2/configure --enable-multilib --enable-targets=i686-pc-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/opt/crossgcc --with-gmp=/opt/crossgcc --with-mpfr=/opt/crossgcc --with-mpc=/opt/crossgcc --with-system-zlib Thread model: posix gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC)

Comment: what was the sequence for building binutils and gcc? `bunutils then gcc` or `gcc then binutils`? the proper sequence should be `binutils then gcc using the newly built binutils`

Comment: i installed first binutils then gcc-4.7.2 with configure --enable-multilib and --enable-targets=i686-pc-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: you have to use --with-gun-as --with-gnu-ld flags also to specify the binutils in use. And also use proper PATH variable.

Comment: Did this solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you must install gcc-multilib:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib libc6-dev-i386
```